# DWT Syntax TemplateBeginIf & TemplateRepeatIndex

Tags: templating, dwt

I am pushing keywords onto the package with keys like

> Keyword1Title

and pulling them out in my DWT using

> @@Keyword{$TemplateRepeatIndex}Title@@

The problem is I want to test the contents of the variable (i.e. not empty) before writing the surrounding HTML. Like:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="StringLength(TemplateRepeatIndexBasedKey) > 0" -->
<p>@@Keyword{$TemplateRepeatIndex}Title@@</p>
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

Followup to Nuno's comment: StringLength(KeywordTemplateRepeatIndexTitle) always returns false.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try it? I think you can use cond="StringLength(KeywordTemplateRepeatIndexTitle)" in there, due to the order in which it gets evaluated - TemplateRepeatIndex gets converted to the actual value before evaluating the condition - but not sure.

Comment: Hey Chris, welcome to TridionStackExchange. +1 for the question and thanks for asking (and compelling us to answer to keep 100% answered)! ;-)

Comment: I have tried 
StringLength(KeywordTemplateRepeatIndexTitle) - always false

I to thought this would work, based on my error messages from
StringLength(Keyword$TemplateRepeatIndexTitle) - error

Sorry for risking the 100% record :)

Comment: Maybe the "correct" answer is no :)

Comment: Hi Chris,  I dont think this is possible.  The problem is you would need to append the TemplateRepeatIndex value with your current variable within the TemplateBeginIf condition.  This is not possible as far as I'm aware.  One way to work around this is to possibly write a C# tbb that loops through and perhaps remove all empty keys?  That way you won't have to do the check for empty string.

Comment: Thanks @user254, but, I add multiple items for each Keyword to the package (title & meta fields), so I cannot simply remove the empty keys. My loop is on a collection of "dummy" Keyword TCMIds, then within the loop I write out the "value" keys.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `cond` of a `TemplateBeginIf` is interpreted as JScript, so there is a lot you can do in there. I'm just not sure anymore how you would check the value of a variable (like `TemplateRepeatIndex` and the compound `"Keyword" + ${TemplateReleatedIndex} + "Title"). Sorry. :-/

Comment: Seems like something you ought to be able to do within a `TemplateBeginIf`, but after playing around I can't figure out how to get the templating engine to interpret this in the way intended. I have a sneaking suspicion that it'll be possible if you get creative, but it seems that the details of how these things are actually parsed are still pretty obscure to most.

Comment: Yes, it seems like it should be possible! I just can't quite find the right syntax :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Frank mentioned in the comments, there is a lot possible in the `cond` of a `TemplateBeginIf`, but I have to say I'm also not quite sure that you can actually check a compound variable like this.

Only thing I can think of right now is to do the check differently, you could write a [Custom Function](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_EFD94BC0585D4186A13F7F3C3B6F47EA) ([login required for that link](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)) which will do the check for you. But if I'm not mistaking, the outcome of a Custom Function, can not be used as a condition value, so you would need to add the markup to that as a parameter too. For example something like:

```html
@@MyCheck("Keyword${TemplateRepeatIndex}Title", "<p>{0}</p>")@@
```

Then in the `MyCheck` function, you check the package variable for a value and if available write it out. Would work quite well for this example, but if the markup is more complex, might become an issue.

Comment: I think this is my only option. I had considered a [TemplateCallable] function (it was my last resort), but I was hoping to solve it in DWT. Custom Function!

Answer (score 1):

I worked out something similar as following:

```
            <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="'@@${"LinkInternal.LinkInternal".concat(TemplateRepeatIndex)}@@'!=''" -->
            <a  tridion:href="@@LinkInternal.LinkInternal${TemplateRepeatIndex}@@">
            <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
                @@LinkInternal.Image${TemplateRepeatIndex}@@
            <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="'@@${"LinkInternal.LinkInternal".concat(TemplateRepeatIndex)}@@'!=''" -->
            </a>
            <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```